# Trigger Save OnClick() event in Sitecore page editor

Tags: javascript, sitecore, sitecore6

I am trying to trigger the save OnClick() event in the PersonalizationForm c# file so that the personalization components will be updated once the form is closed. Currently I am making the following call:

```
SheerResponse.Eval("$("#scRibbonButton_Save").trigger("click");");
```

The response I am getting is:

```
init {context: document, selector: "#scRibbonButton_Save"}
```

Any ideas on how to call the save button from code behind?

Comment: I can trigger the event after I inspect the element in developer tools

Comment: You can trigger the event after you inspect the element because it's in an iframe. By inspecting the button, you change the context from 'Top' to the Sitecore iframe.